# Why am I getting 0 as the output? Shouldn't it be 40?

Tags: c

Why does the following code output 0 instead of 40?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int volume;

    int length = 5;
    int width = 8;

    volume = length * width;
    printf("%f", volume);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about `printf` format specifiers.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49198720/edit) to include more information.

Comment: If you want to print it is a float (using the %f specifier), then you need to case volume to a float in the printf statement like so: `(float) volume`

Comment: use printf("%d", volume); to get 40 instead of 0 :)

Comment: You could alternatively write `printf( "%f", (double)volume );`.

Comment: You might’ve been expecting `volume` to be implicitly converted to the correct type, as if you’d written `sqrt(volume);`. For complicated historical reasons, the standards committee decided back in 1989 variadic arguments that match `...` in a function declaration, including the arguments after the format string `printf()`, are different. A few implicit promotions happen that programmers don’t need to worry about unless they’re working with `<varargs.h>`, but there’s no type checking.

Comment: One workaround is that most compilers today will in fact type-check `printf()` and `sscanf()` for you and *warn* you that you’re shooting yourself in the foot—if you tell them to. You might even be able to turn that warning into a compile error. If you’re not getting a warning message from this code, turn on more warnings. (With gcc and clang, I personally use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -std=c11`.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable "volume" is Integer , you need in the printf function to change from %f that is for float variable, to %d that is for print Integer variable.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration of a variable is `int volume;` and you are printing it by format specifier `%f` which belongs to float type of variable. Type casting requires `(float)volume`. In C programming it happens a lot because compiler dependency comes in picture.